# Сохранение указателя на функцию из синглтона в структуре

Tags: c++

Есть структура из указателей на функции:

```
typedef struct
{
    int (*pfnVidInit)();
    ....
} UI_FUNCTIONS;
```

Мне нужно создать и заполнить экземпляр этой структуры.
В си я просто вводил названия функций:

```
static UI_FUNCTIONS gMenuFuncs = {
    Menu_VideoInit,
    ...
};
```

Сейчас решил попробовать на C++ своё меню переделать:

```
static UI_FUNCTIONS gMenuFuncs = {
    Menu::getInstance()->VideoInit,
    ...
};
```

Но компилятор пишет что не может привести `int (Menu::)()` к `int (*)()`
Почему там `(Menu::)`, а не `(*)` и как мне сделать `(*)` ?

Comment: Потому что это метод класса, и этот метод должен вызываться на объекте, а не просто как свободная функция.

Comment: А что мне тогда делать, враппер?

Comment: Покажите больше кода, что такое `VideoInit`, к примеру

Comment: `int (void)` функция: `int Menu::VideoInit()`

Comment: А функцию `VideoInit` нельзя сделать статической и не мучиться? Если нет - то, видите ли, эта функция на самом деле принимает дополнительный параметр - указатель на объект класса... Так что вызвать ее как `int()` у вас никак не получится. По-моему, лучше писать враппер...

Comment: Нет, не статическая

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
struct UiFunctions
{
    std::function<int()> VidInit;
    ....
};


static UiFunctions gMenuFuncs = {
    []{return Menu::getInstance()->VideoInit();},
    ...
};
```

Не забудьте подключить `functional`. Код всё равно мне не нравится, но он максимально приближен к Вашему варианту.

Возможно, придётся обернуть лямбду в `std::function`, т.к. в таком контексте может не получится конвертация. В таком случае следует написать так:

```
static UiFunctions gMenuFuncs = {
    std::function<int()>([]{return Menu::getInstance()->VideoInit();}),
    ...
};
```

P.S. Да, можно было бы оставить указатель на функцию, но я не стал этого делать, т.к., при прочих равных, вариант с `std::function` более универсальный и идиоматичный, в современном C++.